# How To Efficiently Sort a Lot of RGB Colors in Unity

Tags: c#, sorting, unity-game-engine, colors

What would be an efficient way to sort a 1D array of `Unity` `Colors` (they are a RG? I have an array of 921,600 `Color`s (a 1280 by 720 pixel picture). Is there a type of radix sort for this or do you know of any other efficient way to sort that many colors?
By sort I mean say I have some colors, (123, 17, 2), (5, 16, 16), (5, 2, 150), etc. To sort these I sort by R then G then B (there is probably a name for this but I don't know it) so that list sorted would be (5, 2, 150), (5, 16, 16), (123, 17, 2).

Comment: What are you doing that you want to sort a three dimensional quantity?

Comment: Use `Array.Sort` and pass in an `IComparer` that knows how to determine if one `Color` is less than, greater than, or equal to another `Color`.

Comment: If your array is getting very large, you could for example implement a bitonic sorting algorithm in a compute shader and sort your array on the gpu

Comment: What does it mean to "sort" a colour? Why do you want to do that?

Comment: I edited to clarify.

Comment: Out of curiosity could you explain the bigger picture? What are you doing that you found sorting the colors to be the solution.

Comment: This rings like an XY problem

Comment: I'm looking to find the most "vibrant" or the most "standout" color in a frame. First I sort all of the colors then I find the "difference" between all of the colors then I *think* a vibrant color for that frame would be the "average" of the 2 colors with the largest difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any other way then brute force. The best way would be using `Array.Sort<T>` as stated in comments section.

Create this sorting method:

```
    private int SortColors(Color a, Color b)
    {
        if (a.r < b.r)
            return 1;
        else if (a.r > b.r)
            return -1;
        else 
        {
            if (a.g < b.g)
                return 1;
            else if (a.g > b.g)
                return -1;
            else 
            {
                if (a.b < b.b)
                    return 1;
                else if (a.b > b.b)
                    return -1;
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

And then just use it like this:

```
Color[] colors = new Color[] { new Color (5, 2, 150), new Color (5, 16, 16), new Color (123, 17, 2) }; 
Array.Sort<Color> (colors, SortColors);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to find the "brightest" color. You don't need to sort them. You could just for loop through them and find the brightest.

This is very very much pseudo code, but you get the idea.

```
Color brightest = new Color(0, 0, 0);

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
  Color current = list[i];
  if (current > brightest)  // whatever your comparing means
  { 
     brightest = current;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry if it was unclear. I am not trying to find the "brightest" color in the frame. I am trying to find the brightest color possible for that image. For example

Comment: Sorry I hit enter. For example, if the picture was a picture of a brick building then I would be likely looking for a pink or a yellow. Even though there is no pink or yellow in the picture, it is the most "standout" color (of all possible RGB colors) that could be in that frame.